Trouble Connecting to PostgreSQL on Heroku with node-pg-migrate: SSL Configuration Issues
I'm trying to deploy a Node.js application on Heroku that uses PostgreSQL. I'm using node-pg-migrate for database migrations, but I'm running into issues with SSL connection settings. Heroku requires SSL for PostgreSQL connections, but I'm consistently receiving errors related to SSL certificates.
Here´s my JSON file
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "node dist/src/services/server.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
    "migrate": "node-pg-migrate",
    "migrate-up": "node-pg-migrate up",
    "migrate-create": "node-pg-migrate create"
  },

Here's my migrate-pg-config.js configuration:
require('dotenv').config();
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
    connectionString: isProduction
        ? `${process.env.DATABASE_URL}?sslmode=require`
        : process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: isProduction ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : undefined,
    dir: './migrations',
};

And here is my databaseConfig.ts
require('dotenv').config();

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const databaseConfig = {
  connectionString: isProduction 
    ? `${process.env.DATABASE_URL}?sslmode=require` 
    : process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: isProduction ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : undefined,
   schema: 'public',
  migrationsTable: 'migrations',
};

export default databaseConfig;

The deploy works fine, but the release fails and gives this error:
> api@1.0.0 migrate-up
> node-pg-migrate up
could not connect to postgres: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxxxx", user "xxxxxxx", database "xxxxxxxx", no encryption
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 173,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '536',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
}
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxxxxx", user "xxxxxx", database "xxxxx", no encryption
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 173,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '536',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
}

When I run migrations on Heroku´s Console  npm run migrate-up, I get the following error:
could not connect to postgres: Error: self-signed certificate
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12) {
code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
}

I've tried adjusting the SSL settings in various ways, but I still can't establish a secure connection. Does anyone have experience configuring SSL for PostgreSQL on Heroku with node-pg-migrate? Any advice on how to resolve these SSL certificate issues would be greatly appreciated.
